# A phrase for a small role in a much larger project?

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm writing a thank you letter for a professor whose lab I am working in and I play a fairly small role. Although I have a very tiny part, for me the lab is a huge part of my life.

Is there an English saying that describes a small part of the whole? Like a tiny screw in the machine or a walk-on in a play? I was going to go something like "a small keg in the brewery" but I don't know if that makes much sense.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might use "[a small cog in a big wheel](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+little+cog+in+a+big+wheel)" but I'm not sure that's exactly what you're aiming for.

Comment: Or "a small fish in a big pond".